# Getting IPv4/IPv6 dual stack servers to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of :: on machines where ipv6 is disabled?

Tags: ip, ipv6

I have a Linux (Ubuntu Groovy) server that is booted with kernel option `ipv6.disable=1` so IPv6 is not available.

I also have some dual stack software that advertises it works with IPv4 only machines and that I cannot change. This software now wants to bind to `::`, which of course fails. Can I somehow configure the OS to make this server bind to `0.0.0.0` and use IPv4 instead?

Edit: Alternatively, can this be done before binding, during name resolution? The software tries to resolve `::`, and if it would get IPv4 address `127.0.0.1` as a response, I think it would use IPv4.

Comment: Could you reconsider re-enabling IPv6? The programs binding to `::` would work with both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: In this case this is not an option, regretfully. It sure would be the best option, though...

Comment: Just check uf ipv6 is enabled before binding , and bind to `0.0.0.0` or `::` accordingly

Comment: Use a proxy. Try "socat TCP6-LISTEN:<blah> ,fork TCP4:<blah>"

Comment: Would you mind sharing what this software is?  Do you know what language it's written in?  In rare cases this can be a limitation of the language, but in such cases there may be a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for won't work even if it was possible. If the software is binding to :: then it can assume the addresses will be presented to it in IPv6 format.  The sockets that get accepted will be IPv6 and the IPv4 address will be encapsulated.

So 192.168.1.1 becomes ::FFFF:192.168.1.1

In other words even if you could somehow bind to a different IP you'd be making it an IPv4 socket which the software is not compiled to handle.  The software needs this to be an IPv6 socket only it can't because IPv6 has been disabled.

There is no compatibility code when disabling IPv6.  The bottom line is you disabled IPv6 and the software you are using requires it to be enabled.

---

Your only option here is enable IPv6 (its unclear from your question why you need it disabled) or recompile the IPv6 software yourself from source, possibly patching the source code to "fix" the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is compromise: enable IPv6 but don't allow it to be effectively used anywhere.

Boot with IPv6 enabled, but disable it on future and current interfaces by using `sysctl -w ...` with the parameters below or adding these parameters in `/etc/sysctl.conf`/`/etc/sysctl.d`:

```
  net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
  net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

With this IPv6 use is effectively disabled, while the IPv6 socket API stays enabled. So an application can still bind to `::` and gets IPv4 also associated to it in dual stack mode (this is by default, as per [RFC 3493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3493#section-5.3)).

You might consider exceptions and issues about ::1 on the *lo* interface, depending on configuration and applications behavior. Among multiple choices:

- remove from `/etc/hosts` an entry that would look like this:

  ```
  ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  ```
- or don't disable IPv6 on *lo* (after previous settings) to get ::1 :

  ```
  net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0
  ```
- if the choice was to keep the entry in `/etc/hosts`, ponder giving precedence to 127.0.0.1 over ::1, or anyway simply IPv4 over IPv6 by adding in `/etc/gai.conf`:

  ```
  precedence ::ffff:127.0.0.1/128 100
  ```

  or:

  ```
  precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
  ```

---

Caveat: some network configuration tools (such as NetworkManager) will reset the `disable_ipv6` toggle to their own setting and must thus be explicitly configured to disable IPv6 on the configured interface instead.

Alternate method: if this is too cumbersome to be acceptable, here's an alternate method to disable IPv6 (on kernels with `CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER`, all main distribution kernels do).

Prevent IPv6 routing rules to use routing tables by replacing the *preference 0* rule with a *blackhole* rule making any IPv6 route lookup fail (one could just remove all rules, including preference 32766, to get `Network is unreachable` instead of `Invalid argument`):

```
ip -6 rule delete preference 0
ip -6 rule add preference 0 blackhole
```

Even without any other setting on any interface:

```
$ ping ::1
ping: connect: Invalid argument
ping ff05::2
ping: connect: Invalid argument
```

While listening to IPv6 still succeeds (and defaults to dual stack as per RFC):

```
$ socat tcp6-listen:4242 /dev/null &
[1] 430541
$ ss -tnle sport == 4242
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port                     
LISTEN  0       5                   *:4242             *:*           uid:1000 ino:5971821 sk:1106 v6only:0 <->
```

It can still receive IPv4 traffic in dual stack mode since IPv4 routes are left unhindered.